# Make background-color transition not fade and hover for specific time to click the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="article">
            <a href="#">Here is a text containg something</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    <style>
#wrapper {
height:200px;
width:500px;
 background:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-06iGd_Ue9dk/UqPzuA1Kw7I/AAAAAAAACPc/hBtKtRBSDGE/s1600/Pattern-call.png);
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s linear;
  transition: background-color 2s linear;
}
#article {
 background: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5BAxq07aDQA/UgdY3Mk8spI/AAAAAAAAB84/ElxocGOzgYA/s1600/Opacity.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin-top:50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    padding:10px;
    position: relative;
    top:60px;
}
#article a {color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.hover {
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}
</style>
<script>
$('#wrapper > div').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
})
</script>
```

I am facing 2 problems now - 
 1. I do no want the fade effect on hover but a transition in which the background-color would change starting from the left and end at right. (As we see in loading effect)
 2. Secondly, as the background change is complete I want the browser to redirect the user to the anchor link (the cursor is stil in hover state)

I am facing problem in setting up the two. Your help would be appreciated.

Here is a jsfiddle I have made http://jsfiddle.net/MjkC5/1/ for your reference.

Finally got a link of what sort of thing I want in transition see this page http://bloggingstory-shameer.rhcloud.com/sample-post-for-ghost/ See how the background changes with the loading of page I want same sort of effect. CSS is preferable but I dont mind Jquery too.

Comment: Please explain the problem more clearly. I can't get it.
Thanks

Comment: Question updated see the last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does exactly what you want. See if it helps.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).load(function(){
            $('.animated_div').animate({ 'width':'300px'   }, 2000);


         })


        </script>

        <style type="text/css">

        .wrapper {width:300px; height:100px; background:#000; position:relative;}
        .animated_div {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:0px; height:100px; background:#BABABA;}


        </style>

        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!--you can put anything inside here-->

        <div class="animated_div">

        </div>   
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Thanks